# The best way to dress a human model

Tags: three.js, 3d-modelling

I have an application that works now. But the logic of working is very simple. I think it can be done better.

The working logic of the following application:

-> 3D models are designed separately. Outputs in .obj format.

-> Three.js scene created and models imported.

-> The old outfit has been removed from the stage for changing clothes.

-> Now new outfit has been added to the scene.

Sample code:

```
                    scene.remove(root);

                    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader2();
                    objLoader.setPath('model/');                   

                    objLoader.load( model_name + '.obj', (event) => {
                        var root = event.detail.loaderRootNode;    
                        scene.add(root);       
                    });
```

file structure example:

```
 1. /index.html
 2. /model/
           human.obj
           first_shoes.obj
           twice_shoes.obj
           hat.obj
```

**What I dream of doing: making changes to the single model output.**

**for example; 1.hat hide -> 2.hat show**

image of my application : https://ibb.co/DRMvT32

Please help how to help correct more accurately

Comment: The [`Object3D.visible`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.visible) property (`true` == visible, `false` == invisible) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: How can I reference the children of the object

Comment: [`Object3D.children`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.children). :)  Everything in the scene is derived from `Object3D`, so it's a good place to start for most things.

Comment: I'm pretty new. thank you for your interest